# How to allow only the pull request author to merge it?

Tags: github, merge, github-actions, pull-request

I want to allow only the pull request author to merge it.

I have a GitHub repository with branch protection, ownership to request mandatory reviews, and a minimum number of reviews set for pull requests.

However, all these checks happen before someone click on merge.

Here is an example:

1. User A create a pull request.
2. User A cannot merge it until it passes all the checks and has at least one approval.
3. User B approves the pull request (*User B has the right to commit to the repository*)

Now, I don't want User B to merge the pull request. However, because User B didn't commit, User B triggered no checks.

Two solutions come to mind, but both could be wrong:

1. Create a GitHub Action that triggers on "Click Merge" *(will have to deal with `merge queue`)*
2. Create a check that verifies the username

I don't know to set up any of these solutions. The only piece of answer I found after much research was this article: [How to get the author of a PR?](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25502)

I will appreciate any help,

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if User B has a right to commit, you cannot remove its access to the merge button.

The only way to remove user B's right to press the button is to remove it for everyone using branch protections, and only allow a GitHub App to merge.

You could leverage an app such as Mergify to then write a rule that matches what you described there.